# Prove that the spectrum of normal matrices is stable under small perturbations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a normal matrix.

As shown for example in these notes ([link to pdf](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/80fe/b17468fa5938a02af462c542cd02ed252abd.pdf), see pagg. 120 and 121), given a matrix $B$ with a single non-zero entry and some parameter $\varepsilon\in\mathbb R$, the spectrum of $A+\varepsilon B$ is the same as that of $A$ up to $\mathcal O(\epsilon)$ terms.

This is easily seen by expressing $A$ in its eigenvectors basis, in which it's diagonal. Then, if $B$ has a single off-diagonal element, then $\sigma(A+\varepsilon B)=\sigma(A)$. If, instead, $B$ has a single element on the diagonal, then clearly $\sigma(A+\varepsilon B)=\sigma(A)+\mathcal O(\varepsilon)$.

In the above link is stated that this holds true also for a generic matrix $B$, not just a single-entry one. How is this more general case proved?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/when-are-eigenvalues-stable/

Comment: It suffices to note that $B$ can be written as the sum of single-entry matrices

Comment: @Leo those notes focus on the non-normal case as far as I can tell, though. They mention the same result I'm referring to here but I don't see it proven there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $\sigma(A+\epsilon B)=\sigma(A)+\mathcal O(\epsilon)$.
Write $B$ as sum over its components: $B=\sum_{ij}B_{ij}e_i e_j^*$.

Then,
$\sigma(A+\epsilon B)=\sigma\left(A+\sum_{ij}\epsilon B_{ij} e_i e_j^*\right)$,
thus we can just apply $\sigma(A+\epsilon e_i e_j^*)=\sigma(A)+\mathcal O(\epsilon)$ $N^2$ times to obtain the result.